# Python 3 - write parsed XML data to .csv or .txt file

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am trying to log in to a website, parse the XML data and write the data to a .csv or .txt (either will work) file rather than print on the screen.  The code below does everything except write all data to the .txt file - it will only write the last line of the output.

My current code is:

```
import urllib.request
import time
from lxml import etree
import datetime
import csv
import sys

today = datetime.date.today()
ts = int(time.time()) - 86400
tsend = int(time.time())
dailyReport = "URL_Goes_here".format(ts, tsend)

with urllib.request.urlopen(dailyReport) as url:
    soup = url.read()

saveFile = open('{}_dailyReport.xml'.format(today),'wb')
saveFile.write(soup)
saveFile.close()

tree = etree.parse('{}_dailyReport.txt'.format(today))
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.tag, root.attrib)
for assetidle in root.findall('assetidle'):
    for element in assetidle:
        for event in assetidle.findall('event'):
            zonarFile = open('idleData.txt','w+')
            fleet = assetidle.get('fleet')
            eventtype = event.get('type')
            length = event.find('length').text
            zonarFile.write('Asset #:  %s  %s  %s' %(fleet,eventtype,length))
            zonarFile.write("\n")
            print('Asset #:  %s  %s  %s' %(fleet,eventtype,length))
```

The output on screen is:

```
eventlist {'start': '1461253877', 'end': '1461340277', 'count': '31', 'ver': '1'}
Asset #:  070  idle  00:21:46
Asset #:  130  idle  00:27:09
Asset #:  004  idle  00:35:42
Asset #:  133  idle  00:26:04
Asset #:  060  idle  00:31:36
Asset #:  049  idle  00:45:06
Asset #:  120  idle  00:33:58
Asset #:  135  idle  00:20:04
Asset #:  044  idle  00:20:45
Asset #:  042  idle  00:44:17
Asset #:  114  idle  00:37:49
Asset #:  121  idle  00:21:55
Asset #:  033  idle  00:28:11
Asset #:  138  idle  00:21:14
Asset #:  059  idle  00:25:39
Asset #:  059  idle  00:43:03
Asset #:  058  idle  00:21:26
Asset #:  041  idle  00:26:28
Asset #:  045  idle  00:21:32
Asset #:  005  idle  00:26:48
Asset #:  CAR - 29  idle  00:28:09
Asset #:  C-48  idle  00:20:13
Asset #:  C-47  idle  02:45:04
Asset #:  C-47  idle  00:37:16
Asset #:  C-47  idle  02:03:45
Asset #:  C-47  idle  00:22:28
Asset #:  C-47  idle  10:28:07
Asset #:  C-47  idle  00:43:31
Asset #:  C16  idle  00:29:31
Asset #:  57  idle  00:20:44
Asset #:  74  idle  00:21:34
```

This is the only data that is in the txt file:

```
Asset #:  74  idle  00:21:34
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You appear to be reopening the file inside the loop, *over`w`riting its content each time*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you open your file inside the for loop, write once and then open your file again and again inside the for loop thereby erasing all the content of the file which eventually writes only the last line

move

`zonarFile = open('idleData.txt','w+')`

outside the for loop or change it to

```
zonarFile = open('idleData.txt','a')`
```

which opens the file in `append` mode and adds content to it instead of overwriting the file's contents every time it's opened